# How do I put a bulleted list behind a spoiler tag?

Tags: support, spoilers, formatting

I get that typing ">! text" puts the text behind a spoiler, e.g:

> text

And I get that typing " - text" buts the text in a bullet point, e.g.:

- text

How can I get the bullet into a single spoiler?
">! - text" doesn't work:

> - text1
>  - text2

and " - >! text" doesn't use a single spoiler e.g.:

- > text1
- > text2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a little cumbersome, but you can use HTML:

```
>! <ul>
>! <li>bullet 1</li>
>! <li>bullet 2</li>
>! </ul>
```

produces

> - bullet 1
> - bullet 2

As GentlePurpleRain notes, not all tags are required, but if you omit the `<ul>` and `</ul>`, the bullets will have a strange alignment:

```
>! <li>bullet 1
>! <li>bullet 2
```

produces

> bullet 1
>
> bullet 2

I've seen many users not bothering too much about this and just accept non-formatted lists. For example,

```
>! - bullet 1  
>! - bullet 2
```

(note the trailing spaces) produces

> - bullet 1
>  - bullet 2

and you can use other characters than `-` for the bullets as well.

Comment: That looks like a bit of a hassle. Thanks very much!

Comment: Note that properly-formatted HTML is not required.  A simple
`>! <li> List item one`
`>! <li> List item two`
will suffice, and is considerably less cumbersome.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain that causes the bullets to coincide with the vertical line, which doesn't look too nice (see above). The closing `</li>` tags can indeed be omitted.